# Trying to deploy my smart contract to ropsten testnet but keep receiving this error - ReferenceError: Secret is not defined

Tags: solidity, contract-development, openzeppelin, hardhat, binance-smart-chain

[image: This is the error, it should have deployed the contract]

[image: This the error (sensitive information, meta mask private key blurred and so the moralis io testnet code]
[image]
The last one is Hardhat.config.js

This the error (sensitive information, meta mask private key blurred and so the moralis io testnet code

ReferenceError: Secret is not defined
at Object. (/Users/sarhangsaid/Documents/Code 2 - Hardhat /hardhat.config.js:26:12)

at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)

How do I fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "/Users/sarhangsaid/Documents/Code 2 - Hardhat /hardhat.config.js:26:12" is the place to look. You are probably referencing Secret incorrectly

Comment: @lain is right, can you upload the file hardhat.config.js please ?

Comment: @hroussille, I have uploaded the hardhat.config.js file

Comment: @lain I have uploaded the hardhat.config.js file

Comment: I mean, the error message says exactly what the problem is: hardhat.config.js, line 26, `Secret` is not defined. Check your typo

Comment: True.. line 26 should be `url: secret.url,` and not `url:Secret.url,`